# How to unassign/delete usergroup from role progmatically in Liferay 6.2

Tags: liferay, liferay-ide

Im trying to remove usergroup from role using the following method. But it doesn't work. Can some one help me to identify the problem?

```
  public static boolean  deleteUserGroupFromRole( String groupName, String roleName )
    {
        try
        {
            company = CompanyLocalServiceUtil.getCompanyByMx( PropsUtil.get( PropsKeys.COMPANY_DEFAULT_WEB_ID ) );
            long companyId = company.getCompanyId();

            UserGroup lportalUserGroup=   SoasLportalGroupHelper.getLportalUserGroup( groupName);
            Role role=  getRole( companyId, roleName );


            GroupLocalServiceUtil.deleteRoleGroup(role.getRoleId(), lportalUserGroup.getGroupId() );

            logger.debug( "Role : "+roleName +" has been deleted from groupName "+groupName);
            return true;
        }
        catch ( PortalException e )
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch ( SystemException e )
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Use API methods of `com.liferay.portal.service.UserGroupGroupRoleLocalServiceUtil`

Comment: Thanks pankaj.Acutally the method works i was checking the wrong ui for the result my bad